# how to start the tomcat server in linux?

Tags: centos, installation, tomcat6, startup

i tried to install

```
1.yum install -zxvf apache-tomcat-6.0.47.tar.gz then 
   2.  export TOMCAT_HOME=/home/mpatil/softwares/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
   3. [root@localhost mpatil]# echo $TOMCAT_HOME 
      /home/mpatil/softwares/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
```

while starting tomcat by using this command

```
 4.[root@localhost mpatil]# /startup.sh 
bash: /startup.sh: No such file or directory
```

i don't know why it showing like this.

my file in

```
      5.[root@localhost mpatil]#  find /home -type f -name   apache-tomcat-6.0.37.tar.gz
/home/mpatil/Downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.37.tar.gz
```

what i tried before this is is correct or not? --please tell me my question is how to start a tomcat server in linux.Please tell me..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because both the question and your attitude are inappropriate for SF. Please take a look at our help topics and familiarise yourself with how it works. Additionally, nobody here is under an SLA to respond to you so I'd suggest some courtesy and patience when dealing with other members.

Comment: The more appropriate way to handle installing tomcat6 to CentOS is to do it through the official packages, `yum install tomcat6`, at which point it will be installed to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /home/mpatil/Downloads/
tar zxvf apache-tomcat-6.0.37.tar.gz
cd apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin
./startup.sh
```

Comment: your  command `./startup.sh`  `[root@localhost bin]# ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/mpatil/Downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/mpatil/Downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/mpatil/Downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/soft/jdk1.7.0_21
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/mpatil/Downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin/bootstrap.jar`

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/RUNNING.txt